# Auto play(áudio) com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Existe algum método de dar auto play com áudio, já tentei varias formas mas nenhuma deu certo. Geralmente funciona em um pc e no pc de teste não funciona.

Já fiz o teste com iframe, video, audio, direto no Js e com Api do Youtube.

```
<audio id="musica" autoplay="true">
    <source src="/home/musicas/teste.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="/home/musicas/teste.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 2):

Como não tenho pontos suficientes para comentar, coloco aqui:

O Chrome bloqueia o autoplay com som quando o usuário não realizou nenhuma interação com a página por medidas de segurança. Como especificado [aqui](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes), em `New behaviors`.

> As you may have noticed, web browsers are moving towards stricter autoplay policies in order to improve the user experience, minimize incentives to install ad blockers, and reduce data consumption on expensive and/or constrained networks. These changes are intended to give greater control of playback to users and to benefit publishers with legitimate use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione a chamada via JavaScript no corpo do seu html, desta forma assim que a página for renderizada o JS vai ser executado:

```
function play() {
  document.getElementById("musica").play();
}

play();
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funciona com esse método.

Comment: verdade, essa atualização do chrome realmente bloqueou isso. Acho que você vai ter que dar play quando o usuário fizer alguma interação, como um clique, ou algo do tipo